# How to use Group by of two elements in an object and get the count in List?

Tags: c#, linq, list, count, group-by

I have a List(Student) where Student class is like

```
public class Student
{
    string Name;
    string Class;
    string Division;
}
```

I have an other class like StudentCount.

```
public class StudentCount
{
    string Class;
    string Division;
    string Count;
}
```

I have to populate the List(StudentCount) from List(Student).

SQL statement for above result

```
select Class,division,count(*) 
from Student
group by Class, Division
```

**Students Data**

```
Name - Class - Division

Aa   -   1    -   A

Bc   -   1    -   A

Cc    -  1   -    B

Dd   -   2    -   A
```

I am looking for a result like

**Expected Result**

```
Class - Division - Count

1    -    A     -    2

1 -       B       -  1

2  -      A   -      1
```

I have the student data in a List (Student). 
I have to get the result in List (StudentCount)

Can anyone help to achieve the result through in C#?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Questions on StackOverflow are expected to show some level of effort on behalf of the asker...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an anonymous object for grouping:

```
var groups = data.GroupBy(item => new { item.Class, item.Division });
                 .Select(item => new StudentCount 
                                     { 
                                         Class = item.Key.Class, 
                                         Division = item.Key.Divison,
                                         Count = item.Count()
                                     });
```

Comment: he want the count also :(

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you promote your internal fields to public properties, I believe the following Linq query fulfills your requirements.

```
students
    .GroupBy(s => new{s.Class, s.Division})
    .Select(g => new StudentCount{Count = g.Count(),
                                  Class = g.Key.Class, 
                                  Divison = g.Key.Division})
```

Comment: @OndrejJanacek : What does your edit bring to the table except for a Resharper warning about redundant code? `Class = ` and `Division = ` are redundant, but I'm not entering an editwar to fix it.

Comment: I actually thought that it is necessary to specify properties you are assigning to when you use object initializers.

Comment: ...not if the name is a perfect match to the mapped property.

Comment: `Count` is of type string!

Comment: I don't want to repeat that stupidity. I'm sure the OP can have a string if they really want one. I don't.

Comment: @spender I'm getting a compile error "Cannot initialize type StudentCount" with a collection initializer ...

Comment: Turn your fields into public auto-properties.

Comment: @spender Did not helped.

Answer (score 1):

First make your class members `public` (However its not recommended to have public fields in the class). Like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name;
    public string Class;
    public string Division;
}
```

Then use this:

```
 var groups = data.GroupBy(item => new { item.Class, item.Division })
                  .Select(item => new StudentCount()
                  {
                      Class = item.Key.Class,
                      Division = item.Key.Division,
                      Count = item.Count().ToString() //the Count is of type string, so don't forget to make the proper conversion
                  });
```